# Makefile directory rule dependency rebuild

Tags: makefile, compilation, gnu-make

I got Makefile like this

```
all: sub-dir my-rule

sub-dir:
    $(MAKE) -C $@

my-rule: sub-dir
    g++ main.cpp

.PHONY sub-dir
```

So basically I want to wait for sub-dir to finish before building my-rule but my-rule is rebuilt everytime - even if there where no changes in sub-dir.

How can I make it to wait for sub-dir and rebuild my-rule only when there were changes in sub-dir?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write a rule like:

```
my-rule: sub-dir
```

the target (`my-rule`) will be rebuilt if the prerequisite (`sub-dir`) is newer.  Make doesn't care whether the target or prerequisite are files are directories, only what their last modified time is.

Your makefile has many issues.  The simplest one is that you never create a target `my-rule`, so as far as make is concerned that target is *always* out of date (non-existent == out of date).

You have to write your rule like this so that the recipe updates the target:

```
my-rule: sub-dir
        g++ main.cpp -o $@
```

Of course change `my-rule` if that's not the program you want to create.

Second, directory modification times are updated when the *directory* changes.  The directory changes when something in that directory is renamed, added, or removed.  So if you invoke the sub-make and the sub-make renames, adds, or removes something in that directory then the `my-rule` target will be out of date.  If nothing is renamed, added, or removed, then `my-rule` will *NOT* be out of date.

In general you almost never want to list a directory as a prerequisite.  Instead, you should list the targets that the sub-make creates as the prerequisite, like this (supposing the sub-make creates `libfoo.`):

```
sub-dir/libfoo.a: FORCE
        $(MAKE) -C $(@D)
FORCE:

my-rule: sub-dir/libfoo.a
        ...
```

The `FORCE` rule is there to force the sub-make to be invoked even if `sub-dir/libfoo.a` already exists.

Comment: Well, you almost always want a directory to be an order-only dependency when you build results go into their own directory. E.g. object files depend on their directory. Would be great if GNU Make could create directories for targets automatically.

Comment: In this case we know the directory already exists, because it contains a makefile (and presumably source code).  The order-only prerequisite trick is only needed if you're writing object files to a separate directory that might not already exist.

Comment: What if I have multiple files to build inside sub-dir?

Comment: You can make multiple targets like the one I show above.  It will re-invoke make once per target which is unfortunate but unless your makefiles are very large and complex you won't really notice it.  Alternatively you'll have to get fancier and have a single target that all the sub-targets depend on, to do the sub-make.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Note that as of GNU make 4.3 a new feature "grouped targets" is available, that will allow you to tell make that a single invocation of a rule (that runs a sub-make for example) generates many target files.  This makes it a little simpler to handle the situation in the comment from May 25 2018.